# Is there a particular order of adjectives in french language?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Is there a particular order of adjectives in french language?

For example, "The young blond swedish lady" is
"La jeune femme suédoise blonde" or "La jeune femme blonde suédoise"?

Comment: Note that in this particular case, the french would take advantage that *suédoise* can also be a noun and is already of the feminine gender, hence drop the *femme* => *La jeune **S**uédoise blonde* ou *la Suédoise jeune et blonde*

Comment: @aCOSwt I'm not sure. "la jeune suédoise" could be a child, but "la jeune femme suédoise" certainly couldn't be.